# Summary Query Pivot

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

The query works well until I add the "key" for the 7th importrange I receive a error that says "unable to parse query string for function query parameter 2 no_column col3"

Originally I ended it with where Col1 <> ' ' = that worked to get rid of spaces but did not import all the data so I changed to 'is not null'

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000");IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000"); IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000");IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000"); IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000"); IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D100000");IMPORTRANGE ("key","'Total Hours '!A1:D10000") }, "select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 is not null ")

My issue is that I am trying to create a query pivot based on the information I receive back from the importrange:

=ArrayFormula(QUERY(Total!A1:C, "select B, sum(C) GROUP BY B pivot A label sum(C) '2016' ",-1))

Even without the 7th importrange the pivot table is not summing correctly.

Any suggestions is appreciated as I know this just seems complicated.

Thanks Nicki

Comment: What language are you using; I do not recognize `QUERY({...`

Comment: I used google forum and that was a formula I found and it worked so I stuck with it. Trying to self teach myself. Thank you for replying

Comment: Be sure to limit what you read to MySQL-specific stuff; there are significant differences between databases.  See [_Stackoverflow Documentation on MySQL_](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/topics) - it is concise, incomplete, and has some merits.